# Branding a MS SQL BI Server

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, branding

I am working on a MS SQL BI project. Now I have to brand this Server, according to the tutorial from "Guy in a Cube":

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/branding-the-web-portal

Branding the interfaces worked pretty fine and easy, but now I got stucked at designing the mobile reports.

Changing the colors in the "theme" section at the colors.json-File doesn't change any color on the dashboards and mobile Reports. Did I do something wrong? 
My colleague is using my brand package and changed some Fields to `accent`, but only the text color changed from black to white.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can only change the Mobile Reports with SQL Server Mobile Report Publisher(MMSRP) https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50400

Changing the colors in the colors.json file will only change the colors on your reporting server.